# Is acoustic feedback / echo generation possible without electronics? Low tech, Smaller than a room :D

Tags: live-sound, old

I'm looking for a way to hear my own voice like what it sounds like out of my head, what others hear. I read about vocalists or rap musicians practicing on the stairs in a building. I read about recording booths people used to train their voices in the early days of radio.

Is there something like the old passive megaphone but delays the sound instead of amplifying it?

Comment: Sound travels at a certain speed. Distance is the only way to delay the echo without electronics.

Comment: The only way to really hear how other people hear your voice is to record it.

Answer (score 2):

For the purpose you intend, no, there isn't any such thing.

You can obviously get echoes from walls in a room, but at the size you mention, it would be reverb, and you definitely would not be able to hear what you sound like.

Your only option is to record and play back.

For minimal electronics, an old school tape recorder is simple, but like more modern recording solutions, would require measurement of output to ensure it had the same qualities as your original voice.